# ¿Qué algoritmos existen para ir de un orden de un array a otro usando funciones específicas?

Tags: algoritmos, ordenamiento

Me preguntaba qué algoritmos o enfoques existen para poder resolver el siguiente problema.

Teniendo dos arrays (código en Python):

```
arr_start = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
arr_finish = [5,3,6,1,4,2]
```

Y declarando algunas funciones específicas como estas dos, donde la primera corta la matriz en el n-ésimo elemento como si cortara una baraja de cartas y la segunda realiza una mezcla faro (que es una mezcla perfecta de las cartas, cartas mezcladas una a una):

```
def cut_arr(n,arr):
r=[1]*len(arr)
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if (i+n)<len(arr):
        r[i] = arr[i+n]
    else:
        r[i] = arr[i+n-len(arr)]
return r


def faro_shuffle(arr):
r = []

for (a, b) in zip(arr[0:3], arr[3:]):
    r.append(a)
    r.append(b)
arr = r
return r
```

El objetivo del algoritmo sería encontrar cuántas veces y cuáles de las funciones declaradas tenemos que usar para ir de arr_start a arr_finish identificando el camino más corto.

En este ejemplo, el algoritmo que estoy pidiendo nos diría que hagamos una mezcla faro y luego cortaría la matriz en el tercer elemento, obteniendo arr_finish a partir de arr_start.

```
arr1 = faro_shuffle(arr_start)
cut_arr(3,arr1)

Output: [5,3,6,1,4,2]
```

El objetivo en el futuro sería trabajar con arrays más largos y declarar más funciones.

Comment: Esto parece un ejercicio. Cual es la pregunta concreta, que no sea hacer el ejercicio?

Comment: El ejemplo puesto es para intentar explicar qué es lo que haría el algoritmo que estoy buscando. La pregunta concreta es si existen algoritmos y cuáles son que resuelvan este problema (ir de un orden de un array a otro orden de un array usando funciones específicas que le digamos).

Comment: Le doy vuelta a tu pregunta pero no entiendo hacia que apunta. Tienes una lista A y una versión con otro orden de la B, ¿lo que buscas es saber que funciones aplicar para lograr transforma B nuevamente en A? ¿es eso?

Comment: Gracias por contestar @PatricioMoracho. No. Lo que quiero es dada la lista A de la que partimos, y la lista B que es la lista A con otro orden al que queremos llegar usando solamente las funciones especificadas por nosotros, haya un algoritmo que te diga cuantas veces y en qué orden hay que usar esas funciones especificadas (en mi ejemplo las únicas funciones que se pueden usar para llegar de un orden al otro son mezcla faro y cortar el array por el número n).

Comment: Ahora si, Pareciera un problema **NP-completo** (¿lo será?), si fuera así, no hay otra que usar fuerza bruta.

Comment: En caso de usar fuerza bruta ¿hay alguna manera de reducir la complejidad del problema? Ya que si trabajamos con arrays de 52 elementos (como si fuera una baraja), el tiempo de trabajar con esos arrays puede ser muy alto. ¿Quizás usando un heurístico para reducir la complejidad?